# handling ng-model input when its a number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im trying to grab the number from a SSN input field but if the user type "0101010101" the console.log shows "101010101" so it strips the first zero, how can i fix that?

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="number" value="<?php echo set_value('cpr'); ?>" name="cpr" ng-maxlength="10" ng-minlength="10" ng-model="userFormData.cpr" class="form-control" xt-validate msg-required="Du skal udfylde dit CPR-nummer" required>


            var cpr = cprValue;

            console.log(cpr);

            var dd = +cpr.substr(0, 2); // 01
            var mm = +cpr.substr(2, 2); // 02
            var yy = +cpr.substr(4, 2); // 90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the type to text:

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text"
```

Comment: ahh Thanks :) dident know that